# Slots interrupting each other with just one Thread?

Tags: qt, signals-slots

I have a small example using Slots called by mousemovement and mousewheel.

Now i have the problem that when i zoom and move at the same time, first the onZoom-slot is called and before it is finished it is calling the onMouseMoved-slot. That causes the first slot to lock the mutex (in my original program used by another thread) and the second one to wait for it.

How can I prevent the slots to interrupt each other (and why are they doing it in first place since they are in same thread?).

I read something about using Qt::QueuedConnection but that causes an access violation exception.

main.cpp

```
#include "ppi.h"
#include <QtGui/QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    PPI w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

ppi.h

```
#ifndef PPI_H
#define PPI_H

#include <QtGui/QMainWindow>
#include <QGraphicsView>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QWheelEvent>
#include <QgraphicsEllipseItem>
#include <QMouseEvent>
#include <QMutex>
#include <QThread>
#include <QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent>

//#include "ui_ppi.h"

class PPIView : public QGraphicsView
{
        Q_OBJECT

    public:
        PPIView(QWidget * parent = 0)
            : QGraphicsView(parent)
        {};
        ~PPIView(){};

    private slots:
        void wheelEvent(QWheelEvent *event)
        {emit zoom(event);};

    signals:
        void zoom(QWheelEvent *event);

};

class PPIScene : public QGraphicsScene
{
        Q_OBJECT

    public:
        PPIScene(QObject *parent)
            : QGraphicsScene(parent)
        {};

        ~PPIScene(){};

    private:
        void mouseMoveEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event)
        {emit mouseMoved(event);};

    signals:
        void mouseMoved(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event);
};

class PPI : public QMainWindow
{
        Q_OBJECT

    public:
        PPI(QWidget *parent = 0, Qt::WFlags flags = 0)
        : QMainWindow(parent, flags)
        {
            //ui.setupUi(this);
            //ppiScene is inherited from QGraphicsScene, overriding mouseMoveEvent so it emits mouseMoved();
            ppiScene = new PPIScene(this);
            gVPPI = new PPIView(this);
            gVPPI->setMinimumSize(1024,1024);
            gVPPI->show();

            test = new QGraphicsEllipseItem(-10, -10, 20, 20);
            ppiScene->addItem(test);

            gVPPI->adjustSize();

            connect(ppiScene, SIGNAL(mouseMoved(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent*)), this, SLOT(onMouseMoved(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent*)));
            connect(gVPPI, SIGNAL(zoom(QWheelEvent*)), this, SLOT(onZoom(QWheelEvent*)));

            //ui.gVPPI is inherited from QGraphicsView, overriding wheelEvent, so it emits zoom()
            gVPPI->setScene(ppiScene);
            gVPPI->setMouseTracking(true);
        };

        ~PPI(){};

        QMutex mutex;

    private:
        //Ui::ppiClass ui;
        PPIScene* ppiScene;
        PPIView *gVPPI;

        QGraphicsEllipseItem *test;

    protected slots:
        void onZoom(QWheelEvent *event)
        {
            qDebug() << "Zoom lock" << QThread::currentThreadId();
            mutex.lock();
            qDebug() << "Zoom locked";

            if(event->delta() > 0)
                gVPPI->scale(1.01, 1.01);
            else
                gVPPI->scale(1/1.01, 1/1.01);

            qDebug() << "Zoom unlock";
            mutex.unlock();
            qDebug() << "Zoom unlocked";
        };

        void onMouseMoved(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event)
        {
            qDebug() << "Move lock" << QThread::currentThreadId();
            mutex.lock();
            qDebug() << "move locked";

            test->setPos(test->pos()+event->scenePos()-event->lastScenePos());

            qDebug() << "Move unlock";
            mutex.unlock();
            qDebug() << "Move unlocked";
    };
};

#endif // PPI_H
```

Output `qDebug()`:

```
Move lock 0x1514 
move locked 
Move unlock 
Move unlocked 
Move lock 0x1514 
move locked 
Move unlock 
Move unlocked 
Zoom lock 0x1514 
Zoom locked 
Move lock 0x1514
```

Comment: It is not possible, because all GUI in Qt is working in one thread. Your mutex do nothing there. You may check, what thread is executed now. For example (in each slot): `Q_ASSERT( QThread::currentThread() == this->thread() );`

Comment: Thats why I am confused. All slots are running in the same thread, but still iterrupting eachother when moving and scrolling at the same time. I also checked the thread id with `QThread::currentThreadId()` and they are in the same thread. The mutex does something in my example: It causes the program to freeze. If the slots would not interrupt each other that would not happen. I add the output of qDebug()

Comment: I think `ui.gVPPI->scale` somehow triggers a mouse move. You can add a bool member which you set to true bevor and false after the `scale` and execute the move only if it is false for testing

Comment: This question is useless without you posting a complete, self-contained test case. If one merely takes your code at face value and mocks missing functionality so that it compiles, everything is fine. You're shooting yourself in the foot by not providing an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org). I also don't understand why don't you trace your code in the debugger. If you claim that the event loop is reentered, you can simply breakpoint in the supposedly reentering slot and see if other of your slots are on the callstack.

Comment: I added the full code as minimal as i could think off.
The debugger is not working for me, there seems something wrong with the configuration. I first need to ask some co-worker to help me and show me how to use it.

Comment: Thank you very much @Kuba Ober! I finally managed to get my debugger working and it seems that `QGraphicsView::scale()` is calling `QGraphicsScene::mouseMoveEvent()` deep inside directly, which results in something like "interrupting".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to set up my debugger and the problem seems QGraphicsView::scale() is calling QgraphicsScene::mouseMoveEvent() deep inside directly. So I need to introduce a variable which tells the mouseMoveEvent, whether it was called from QGraphicsView::scale() or from physical mouse movement.

```
protected slots:
    void onZoom(QWheelEvent *event)
    {
        qDebug() << "Zoom lock" << QThread::currentThreadId();
        mutex.lock();
        qDebug() << "Zoom locked";

        scale = true;
            if(event->delta() > 0)
                gVPPI->scale(1.01, 1.01);
            else
                gVPPI->scale(1/1.01, 1/1.01);
        scale = false;

        qDebug() << "Zoom unlock";
        mutex.unlock();
        qDebug() << "Zoom unlocked";
    };

    void onMouseMoved(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event)
    {
        if(scale == false)
        {
            qDebug() << "Move lock" << QThread::currentThreadId();
            mutex.lock();
            qDebug() << "move locked";
        }

        test->setPos(test->pos()+event->scenePos()-event->lastScenePos());

        if(scale == false)
        {
            qDebug() << "Move unlock";
            mutex.unlock();
            qDebug() << "Move unlocked";
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `QObject::blockSignals` to block signals for specific object,
but I think you have wrong idea about how your code works.

There is one GUI thread, and if signals + slots in the same GUI thread,
as in your case, then they called in sequence order. And if `PPI::onZoom` will called in another thread context then you have problem here, because of usage of things like `ui.gVPPI->scale` in non GUI thread is not allowed and may cause crash on assert, or just crash, or randomly works, UB as it is.

The situation when you see that `slot 1` was called, then before finish of `slot 1` `slot 2` is called is likely because of you call some function inside `slot 1` that call another function etc and some function deep inside call `signal 2`, which emit call of `slot 2`, just set breakpoints in your debugger and findout what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't make sense to use any form of locking in a single GUI thread that doesn't cooperate with other threads. Everything in the GUI thread is already serialized for you. You're fighting an imaginary problem. As long as your code is executing, nothing else will execute behind your back in the same thread.

> onZoom-slot is called and before it is finished it is calling the onMouseMoved-slot

This is false. Nothing of the sort happens in the code you show. Perhaps `ui.gVPPI->scale()` is reentering the event loop. You really need to show a self-contained example: your problem is in the code you don't show.

> How can I prevent the slots to interrupt each other

It's already prevented for you. You need to do nothing.

> in my original program used by another thread

Generally speaking, objects living in the GUI thread cannot have methods directly invoked from other threads.

Most of the time, throwing a second thread at a problem makes you end up with two problems. Properly designed non-blocking code will work correctly, if perhaps a bit slow, even when run in a single thread. That'd be your point of departure - you then move objects to other threads simply to spread the work around. Ideally, though, async processing should be done by running work asynchronously through `QtConcurrent::run`.